# www to non-www redirection won't work

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm writing a www to non-www redirection with the following code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

However, `www.mywebsite.com` redirects to `mywebsite.com/www/` instead of `mywebsite.com`.

I suspect this might be due to the `DocumentRoot` configuration of a VirtualHost, but I cannot access the httpd.conf file since I'm on a shared environment.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the full URL of the request? And this .htaccess file is presumably in the document root?

Comment: The rule should work as is. The described behaviour can only happen, when you request `http://www.mywebsite.com/www`. Most likely, there's more in your configuration.

Comment: @w3d: full URL is `http://www.mywebsite.com`. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As Olaf suggests in comments, *normally* this should not happen. However, there have been a few questions like this where the hosting account (in a shared environment) is somehow dependent on a *parent* configuration and enabling mod_rewrite inheritance resolves the problem:

```
RewriteOptions Inherit
```

Admittedly, how or why this should work is a bit of a mystery. (Particularly since parent directives are executed *after* child directives, etc. ?)

You can also try changing your `RewriteRule` to use the value of `REQUEST_URI` instead, for example:

```
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]
```

Change to `301` when you are sure it's working OK. Permanent redirects are naturally cached by the browser so can make testing tricky. (Also, clear your browser cache before testing this!)

Comment: thanks for your answer. Investigating further based on your proposal, I discovered that RewriteRule's condition was causing the trouble. Things work properly with `RewriteRule ^ http://%1/$1 [R=302]`, or `RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302]`as well, though `www.mywebsite.com/something`doesn't redirect to `mywebsite.com/something`.

Comment: Just to note, `RewriteRule ^ http://%1/$1 [R=302]` would **not** work, it would need to be the 2nd directive with `REQUEST_URI` if you are using the pattern `^`. The first directive would simply strip the URL-path, so no `www` - but no _anything_! However, are you saying the 2nd one does not work either... are you still losing the `something`? Incidentally, you should use the `L` flag (in case you have any other directives).

Comment: Do you have any other directives in your .htaccess file?

Comment: Ok. Indeed: the first one (`www.mywebsite.com` to `mywebsite.com`) works whereas the second one doesn't (`www.mywebsite.com/something`doesn't redirect to `mywebsite.com/something`). The other directives of the .htaccess file are: `Options All -Indexes`, `ServerSignature Off`, `AddDefaultCharset UTF-8`, `<Files ~ "^.*\.([Hh][Tt][AaPp])">
order allow,deny
deny from all
satisfy all
</Files>` and `ErrorDocument 401 /errors/401.html` (idem 403, 404 and 500). Thanks

Comment: Dear @w3d: does the input help you finding an explanation to this behavior?